# Empty config diffs

Tags: config, projectconfig

We're using Craft Pro 3.8.14 with `allowAdminChanges=false` for production environment. On each deploy, we do

```
./craft migrate/all --interactive=0
./craft project-config/apply
./craft clear-caches/all
```

For some reason, however, we often get a warning that pending changes need to be applied, even though they seem to be empty (see screenshot attached). Do you please know where this might be coming from?[image]